# LISP function for removing a given element from a list does not work

Tags: syntax, lisp

**Here is my code:**

```
(defun remv(a L)
 (if (null L) nil
      (if (typep (first L) 'list) (cons (remv a (first L)) (remv a (rest L)))
           (if (= a (first L)) (remv a (rest L)) (cons (first L) (remv a (rest  L)))))))
```

**When I call it:**

```
(remv a '(a (b) a c))
```

**I get this error:**

> Error: Unbound variable: A
>   While executing: CCL::CHEAP-EVAL-IN-ENVIRONMENT, in process listener(1).
>   Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
>   If continued: Retry getting the value of A.
>   Type :? for other options.
>   1 >

the the function works with numbers , I have looked around and I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Alright, I changed two things in the code: in the function definition I changed the last if statement conditional to (eq a (first L)) and the function call to (remv 'a '(a (b) a c)).

Comment: It works with output: ((B) C)

Answer (score 0):

Just here:

```
(remv a '(a (b) a c))
```

There is a huge difference between `a` alone and `(quote a)`, also written `'a`. The first one is a reference to a variable named after the symbol `a`, which is unbound in your case, while the second one is the symbol named `a` itself.

If your function is supposed to work with numbers and you want to test it to see if it succeeds, give it numbers. Here you are passing a quoted list of symbols as a second argument.